# When should we use FileManager.default.urls as opposed to NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains?

Tags: ios, swift

Currently, if I want to create a directory hierarchy in Document directory, I would perform the following

---

### Using NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains (Works fine)

```
let paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true)
let documentsDirectory = paths[0]
let documentUrl1 = URL(string: documentsDirectory)!
//
// /Users/yccheok/Library/Developer/...
//
print("documentUrl1 -> \(documentUrl1)")

let dataPath = documentUrl1.appendingPathComponent("SubFolder1").appendingPathComponent("SubFolder2")
print("dataPath.absoluteString -> \(dataPath.absoluteString)")
if !FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: dataPath.absoluteString) {
    do {
        try FileManager.default.createDirectory(atPath: dataPath.absoluteString, withIntermediateDirectories: true, attributes: nil)
        print("Folder creation done!")
    } catch {
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }
}
```

---

But, if I use the following

### Using FileManager.default.urls (Not working)

```
let documentUrl0 = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)[0]
//
// file:///Users/yccheok/Library/Developer/...
//
print("documentUrl0 -> \(documentUrl0)")

let dataPath = documentUrl0.appendingPathComponent("SubFolder1").appendingPathComponent("SubFolder2")
print("dataPath.absoluteString -> \(dataPath.absoluteString)")
if !FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: dataPath.absoluteString) {
    do {
        try FileManager.default.createDirectory(atPath: dataPath.absoluteString, withIntermediateDirectories: true, attributes: nil)
        print("Folder creation done!")
    } catch {
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }
}
```

The following error will be printed

> You can’t save the file “SubFolder2” because the volume is read only.

---

I was wondering, under what use case, that `FileManager.default.urls` will be useful? Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

`URL(string` and `absoluteString` are the wrong APIs to work with file system paths.

Your code accidentally works because `URL(string` applied to a ***path*** creates a path rather than a valid URL, and `absoluteString` applied to a path returns the path because there is no scheme (`file://`).

However you are strongly discouraged from doing that. A file system URL must be created with `URL(fileURLWithPath` and you can get the path with the `path` property.

You are encouraged to use the `FileManager` API because it provides a better error handling and it provides also the URL related API which is preferred over the string path API.

This is the correct `FileManager` way to create the directory if it doesn't exist

```
let fm = FileManager.default
do {
    let documentUrl = try fm.url(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask, appropriateFor: nil, create: false)
    //
    // file:///Users/yccheok/Library/Developer/...
    //
    print("documentUrl -> \(documentUrl)")
    
    let dataURL = documentUrl.appendingPathComponent("SubFolder1").appendingPathComponent("SubFolder2")
    print("dataPath.path -> \(dataURL.path)")
    if !fm.fileExists(atPath: dataURL.path) {
        try fm.createDirectory(at: dataURL, withIntermediateDirectories: true, attributes: nil)
        print("Folder creation done!")
    }
} catch { print(error) }
```

In iOS 16+, macOS 13+ you can replace

```
let documentUrl = try fm.url(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask, appropriateFor: nil, create: false)
...
let dataURL = documentUrl.appendingPathComponent("SubFolder1").appendingPathComponent("SubFolder2")
```

with

```
let documentUrl = URL.documentsDirectory
...
let dataURL = documentUrl.appending(components: "SubFolder1", "SubFolder2")
```

Comment: I have delelete the created folders, and re-test with my first example code, and your proposed code. Both works fine for me. It seems my `documentUrl1.appendingPathComponent(...).absoluteString` are having same value as your `dataURL.path`.

Comment: Nevertheless `absoluteString` is wrong. Don't use it with file system URLs. Your code accidentally works because `URL(string` applied to a path creates a path, not an URL. So the `absoluteString` API doesn't cause harm. But once again, it's wrong.